# postfix notation - Stack pop and push help, incorrect return value being returned for mod or pow operator

Tags: c, return-value, postfix-notation, postfix-operator

my code is relatively simple in what it aims to do, it takes in command line arguments and places the stack accordingly.

command line argument: "2 2 +" should equal 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct stack {

    int top;
    int items[100];

} stack;

void initializeStack(stack* p);
void push(stack* p, int val);
int pop(stack* p);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int i, a, b;
    int val = 0;
    stack ph;
    initializeStack(&ph);

    for(i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "*") == 0) {
            a = pop(&ph);
            b = pop(&ph);
            val = a*b;
            push(&ph, val);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "/") == 0) {
            a = pop(&ph);
            b = pop(&ph);
            val = b/a;
            push(&ph, val);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "+") == 0) {
            a = pop(&ph);
            b = pop(&ph);
            val = a+b;
            push(&ph, val);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "-") == 0) {
            a = pop(&ph);
            b = pop(&ph);
            val = b-a;
            push(&ph, val);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "^") == 0) {
            a = pop(&ph);
            b = pop(&ph);
            val = pow(a,b);
            push(&ph, val);
        }

        else if(strcmp(argv[i], "%") == 0) {
            a = pop(&ph);
            b = pop(&ph);
            val = b%a;
            push(&ph, val);
        }

        else {
            push(&ph, atoi(argv[i]));
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", pop(&ph));

    return 0;
}

void initializeStack(stack* p) {
    p->top = 0;
}

void push(stack* p, int val) {
    p->top++;
    p->items[p->top] = val;
}

int pop(stack* p) {
    int y;
    y = p->items[p->top];
    p->items[p->top] = 0;
    (p->top)--;
    return y;
}
```

I've tried "2 2 +" and it has worked, and so has "2 4 + 3 / 6 +", it has evaluated to 8. but then there's this problem, where "2 4 ^ 2 * 5 % 2 -" where it should evaluate to 0 but I get -2 instead. what is the flaw here?

Comment: maybe it's my compiler? I don't understand. I executed the same thing, and got -2.

Comment: What is your command line ? Did you despecialized the * ? Modify your code and print first the args, to be sure that your env did not introduced some weird behaviour (escapings, expansions, etc).

Comment: the * will be interpreted as all files in the current folders, therefore you need to write "*" instead of *

Comment: ok, when I print out my arguments, I get, "2 4 ^ 2 bin main.c main.c.cbTemp obj postfixnotation.cbp postfixnotation.depend postfixnotation.layout 5 % 2 - -2"

Comment: Your code never uses `items[0]`, since you increment `top` *before* storing, which is odd. Not sure if that's an error, but it's scary since you risk overflowing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as written in the comments: you have to put the * under ", otherwise it will be expanded to all files in the current folder. so cal it with

```
 ./a.out 2 4 ^ 2 "*" 5 % 2 -
```

and it will work

Comment: I have tried putting it under quotation marks yet it still does the same output.

Comment: which OS are you using?